# i can't understand the following error

Tags: java, list, playframework

this is the error:

> A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Question, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(Choices)]

i can't understand the error i have used lists in other classes but they had relations to other classes, they had types of other classes but here i don't understand why isn't he seeing the type of the list

```
package models;


import play.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;


@Entity
public class Question extends Model{
public String theQuestion;
public int marks;
public List<String> Choices;
@ManyToOne 
@JoinTable (name="questionInEexercise")
public Exercise myExercise;



public Question(String question,int marks,long Eid){
    this.theQuestion = question;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.myExercise = Exercise.findById(Eid);
    Choices = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Comment: For future questions you may want to use a more descriptive question text in order to get more views by people that might know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA won't know how to map your list of Strings correctly.  You could map it with an [ElementCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) so JPA would know how to handle it.